# Should TeX.SE provide the citation extension?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As the citation scripts add load time to the page (as I have been informed by the support) they are only provided on pages, which explicitly request it, like on [Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-a-good-standard-for-publishing-a-reference-to-a-stackexchange-thread) or [CS Theory.SE](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-will-you-cite-a-discussion-on-this-site-in-your-paper).

So I was asked to bring it before the meta.

It seems sensible to provide `bibtex` style citations for TeX.SE, so technical references and acknowledgements can be given where they are due without too much work.

How is the consesus on this in this community?

An example citation for [CS Theory.SE](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-will-you-cite-a-discussion-on-this-site-in-your-paper) looks like this

```
@MISC {352,
    TITLE = {&quot;All-different hypergraph coloring&quot; - known problem?},
    AUTHOR = {Falk H&#252;ffner (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/251/falk-h%c3%bcffner)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/352 (version: 2010-08-20)},
    EPRINT = {https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/352},
    URL = {https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/352}
}
```

[image: The additional cite button]

[image: The citation as it is presented]

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what is meant by "the citation scripts"? Could you also include examples of how this is already used elsewhere on the StackExchange network?

Comment: Should I add more references @Werner ?

Comment: And how will this be used within a post? Can you add an image?

Comment: added two pictures

Comment: Oh, I see... you want to add the option to "cite" a specific TeX.SE post, not add citations *within* a TeX.SE post. So that would add `cite` to the current list of options (`share` `edit` `close` `flag`).

Comment: yes; that was not clear.

the idea is to cite specific versions easily

Comment: Could you provide examples of where this would be useful and better than just linking to the answer? As I see it, answers here only ever get _improved_ (or deleted), so it is quite useful for links to go to the most recent versions. Things may have changed, better solutions been made available since the reference was created.

Comment: The citation of a defined version would make clear, where the work was done;
the newer versions are still available from that version @schtandard.

Comment: If a newer version starts breaking other `hack` depending on the original version, this might be problematic.

Comment: But the more important point for my use case is the `bibtex` generation

Comment: In the case that an answer is useful, you may wish to include it reference list of another publication (and I have done this!). One can easily construct the citation manually for `bibtex`. However, my experience with the various online citation scripts (esp. GoogleScholar) is that they are unreliable in dealing with names (GS actually removes author names when its parser can't figure out how to process it). Also, most of these scripts do not use the correct ordering of complex names in `bibtex`, transposing suffixes and given names, or putting minus signs in place of en dashes in page ranges.

Comment: therefore the generation by SE seems to be the best way to go (and the scripts exist already) @John

Comment: Yes, if the SE scripts do not have the errors. Tex-SE seems like the one venue that should get this right..